# SQL Server 2016 given support to json by providing a set of functions .what about the performance?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2016

In my example I am creating an ASP.NET MVC application using SQL Server 2016, I have two options:

1. a traditional way of creating a table and columns (non json columns)
2. using new json support in SQL Server 2016

Here my columns are fixed, but I am interested to go with json. If I use json every time I pass data to database I need to serialize my model data to json and when I retrieve I need to deserialize it. I want to know using json, will it improve performance of my application?

Comment: **Of course**, serializing and deserializing for every single database access **will significantly slow down** your overall performance. Plus, when you stick everything into JSON format, you will **loose all database support** for things like **referential integrity**, check and default constraints, and much more. **DON'T DO IT!** Might seem like a good idea at first - **IT'S NOT!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it probably won't increase the performance of your application, at least not significantly.  Even without json, you are still moving the data in the objects into SQL Server readable data.

Storing data in SQL Server using json is similar to what is done with nosql databases, e.g. storing data when the number of fields differs greatly or when you don't know the structure up from.

Storing your data in json format in SQL Server certainly has its place, but if you have fixed fields that you know up front, like you do, then you are using it incorrectly and it will come back to haunt you.